# Overlay coastlines on a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I'm looking to overlay some coastlines on graph representing an area. The area is defined by the box:

- Top: 3900000
- Bottom: 3450000
- Left: 300000
- Right: 800000

with the coordinate system WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_36N.

I've tried using mpl_toolkits.basemap however I can't work out how to specify that area as the ESPG code (32636) is not accepted by Basemap, and when I attempt to manually insert the projection parameters (`m = Basemap(projection='tmerc', k_0=0.9996, lat_0=0, lon_0=33, llcrnrx=300000, llcrnry=3450000, urcrnrx=800000, urcrnry=3900000`) it still requires a lat long boundary box.

Is there a another way to define that area in Basemap?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm trying to return an area of coastline defined by a box that is in the utm system, using lat/long values for the extremities of the box would result in over/underlap of the area covered by the coastlines when converted back into the utm system (I think, please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Have you looked at [PyProj](http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/)? Is [this](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2013/12/16/utm/) helpful?

Comment: I'd break it into two pieces, (1) convert your top/bottom/etc to lat/lon corners, then (2) plot using Basemap.  You can use PyProj (as farenorth suggested) or a tiny utility called "utm" which pretty much just does those conversions (you can get it [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm))

Comment: farenorth @Ajean, thanks for your input (especially the utm utility), however please see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cartopy and its new epsg feature:

```
projection = ccrs.epsg(32636)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5),
                      subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection))
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
```

Here is a notebook with an example:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/ocefpaf/832cf7917c21da229564

Comment: Thanks ocefpaf, however please see the edit to my question, I'm not trying to extract the coastlines in a box defined by lat/longs, I'm trying to extract the coastlines in a box defined in the utm system (metres).
These are different things as merideans are straight lines on a sphere, and a constant utm northing is a straight line on a flat map.

Comment: Did you see the notebook?  I do not define a lon/lat bbox.  I am using your UTM coords.

Comment: Yes, you input the UTM coords which were then converted to lat long, and the program extracted the coastlines from the box defined by the lat long box. The straight lines between the vertices of a lat-long box go over a difference place than the straight lines between the vertices of a UTM box. This is the difference that I have been trying to get at.
Another way of looking at it is: if this was not the case why would both lat long and utm co-ordinate systems exist?

Comment: No.  The program extract the coastlines from the EPGS projection code and the axis **IS** defined in **UTM**!!!  The UTM2LonLat is just to check if the values are OK!!!

Comment: @ocefpaf-Sorry, for some reason the way I looked up the coordinates for my original question means they are slightly out from what I was actually after (eg. 80000 instead of 75000), so when I saw the area of coastlines that were returned I thought it was the program that was returning them slightly out.
I don't think I'm ever going to understand why ArcGIS does some of the things it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make sure the value of resolution is a lowercase L,
#  for 'low', not a numeral 1
map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0=57, lon_0=-135,
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=-136.25, llcrnrlat=56,
    urcrnrlon=-134.25, urcrnrlat=57.75)

map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color='coral')
map.drawmapboundary()

map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30))
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30))

plt.show()
```

[image]

All at this link https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-making-a-simple-map/

Comment: Hi Johnathan, thanks for your reply. Perhaps I've misunderstood how the projections work but I thought although you can convert points between lat/long and utm converting a box made from four of those points will result in curved edges of the converted area (admittedly negligible below a certain scale). I've updated my question to be more specific about the utm boundaries.

Comment: I managed install needed libraries in ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8.10 by 
`sudo apt update; sudo apt install libgeos++-dev libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-dev libgeos-doc`
# in correct venv:
`pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip`

working fine!